# Swipe to delete is not working with custom cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am using custom cell and adding tableview programmetically. I am trying to implement swipe functinality in my application. The tableview datasource method are not called when I try to swipe.

```
tableview = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
tableview.delegate=self;
tableview.dataSource=self;


tableview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
tableview.backgroundColor=selectedBackGroundColor;
tableview.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];


tableview.editing=YES;
NSLog(@"%f %f",self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:tableview];
```

and this method is calling

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath 
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

after that even cell is also not selecting...am i missing any thing code please help me out?

Comment: Have added a sub? Have you added your view to the content view? Does your view automatically resizes with it parent?

Comment: yes i added one lable and one image in my custom contentview

Comment: i commented all labels what i added in custom cell.even thougth same. if i swipe then didselectRow ForIndexpath also not calling ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

Then Its Working Fine.....Thanks For answering my Question

Comment: this was the reason of my swipe-to-delete not working....ive been banging my head with the wall for weeks...thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Did you implement `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` in the datasource.

Answer (score 1):

If you have set the tableview to `editing` already I doubt that swipe to delete (and selections if `allowsSelectionDuringEditing` is `NO`) will work at all. Try removing this line:

```
tableview.editing=YES;
```

and see if the swiping is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

use this implementation instead:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        // Delete an object
    }   
}
```